# Python: Boolean return if arbitrary element is in arbitrary list

Tags: python, list, boolean, element, match

Noob wondering how to improve his code.

```
a, b, c = string.split(enteredDate, "/")

m31s = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
m30s = [4, 6, 9, 11]

for x in range(len(m31s)):
    x = int(m31s[x])
    if x != int(a) and b != 31:
         print "Invalid date."
for x in range(len(m30s)):
    et cetera...
```

In case it isn't clear, I am testing an inputted date to see if it is valid. This is only part of the program. **The main question is**: what is the best way to test if an element matches ANY element in a list?

My method works... But, I suspect there is a better way to do this. I said boolean in the title because I envision something like:

```
if secretCode(m31s, int(a)) == True:
```

Could be a pipedream. Just curious.

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to help.

Comment: `31s` is not a valid variable name. variable names can not start with a digit, though they can contain digits.

Comment: Yeah, you're exactly right. I learned that when I ran this earlier--forgot to make the changes in my post. Good catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the syntax `if elem in list`. For example:

```
>>> if 1 in [1,2,3,4,5]:
...     print 'found 1'
... 
found 1
```

Comment: Thanks. This will be prove quite useful!

Comment: BTW I chose your answer because it answered the specific question. Other responses also provided excellent insights.

Comment: Agreed, they're very helpful. You should upvote them to thank them. (I'm about upvote both as well.)

Answer (score 2):

You should use python [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) library.

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(enteredDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
except:
    print 'Invalid date'
```

Comment: +1 for datetime. In the OP's code, `a` appears to be the month, `b` appears to be a date (`31`). So perhaps he wants `%m/%d/%Y`.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to this library. BTW: seems like it should be "%m/%d/%Y"

Comment: Wow, missed your comment unutbu. Sorry for the repetition.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

- replace

  ```
     a, b, c = string.split(enteredDate, "/")
  ```

  with

  ```
     a, b, c = enteredDate.split("/")
  ```

  Not that it matters much, but the first version needs to import the `string` module, the second not.
- replace `int(m31s[x])` with `m31s[x]` (you know those are `int` already, why the extra `int( ... )` then?
- in case `secretCode( ... )` returns true or false you can simply write `if secretCode( ... ):`, no need to compare with `== True`.
- instead of calling `int(a)`, `int(b)` or `int(c)` you can simply write `a, b, c = map(int, enteredDate.split("\"))` and forget about those `int( ... )` later since you know they are int. Additionally, if those are *not* int you will immediately get an exception without unnecessarily progressing in your code.

Comment: Thanks for all the style suggestions. Seriously--it is difficult to get these sorts of minor corrections, which are invaluable to me. If only I could get them more often!